# Shielding issues with RJ45 connectors

Tags: emc, shielding, rj45, emissions

I've been dealing with a pretty nasty radiated emissions problem at work and I've pretty well exhausted any list of potential solutions/mitigation tactics to resolve this given the design constraints. The source of the noise is common-mode noise from this custom legacy interface that uses shielded RJ45 8P8C style connectors. It's a DC-coupled interface that consists of 3 data lines and 1 clock line which runs at 62.5MHz, with a 8Vp-p differential voltage, and a risetime less than 1ns. Our radiated emissions signature has prominent peaks above the CISPR 11 limits at 62.5MHz and its harmonics.

One of the few things my team and I have identified as being a potential issue with this interface is the style of connector that was used. The RJ45 jacks are well grounded to the chassis of the interconnected modules and we use standard Cat6A SFTP cabling with shielded connectors. Using a near-field H-probe and an SA, I've seen  the clock harmonics leaking out where the two connectors mate, but not much is picked up when I run the probe down the length of the cable. We suspected that the backshell terminations of standard shielded RJ45 cable connecters were not well made so we even tried making custom Cat7 SFTP (thicker and more dense braided shield) cables with all metal connectors shown below to better terminate the shield, but sadly it did not yield any significant improvement in the radiated emissions signature.

[image: Metalized RJ45 Connector] [image: Shielded RJ45 Jack]

I suspect that one of the primary reasons this didn't have much of an impact is because the all metal connector does nothing to really improve the mating between the RJ45 Jack and the cable connector. It still relies on two small metal spring tabs inside the connector to make electrical contact, so the transfer impedance between those two is essentially the same. In principle, I think a M12 style connector would be better suited to terminate the cable shield to the chassis thus creating a better return path for the common-mode currents allowing them to flow on the inner surface of the shield between the modules.

I've seen a lot of alternative style RJ45 connectors which have a [circular outer shell](https://www.mouser.com/new/te-connectivity/te-polamco-rj45-connectors/) which I'm sure helps with ruggedization and also improves the shielding effectiveness and EMC. I've also seen [videos of Rick Hartley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9tB6JtG7oQ) expressing his gripes with this style of connector, but not necessarily a complete picture of the issue. I don't have a ton of experience with EMC so I'm not sure my analysis is on the right-track, but I'd like to know if anyone has had issues with radiated/conducted emissions when using RJ45 style connectors or similar concerns regarding their shielding effectiveness.

Comment: Good question. +1. I'm interested in good answers to this.

Comment: "The RJ45 jacks are well grounded to the chassis of the interconnected modules" Now what happens if you only ground the shield at _one_ side?

Comment: Grounding the shield on one side leads to worse radiated emissions performance. I believe a general concern with grounding the shield on both ends is now you form a ground loop and can have ground currents flowing along the shield. However, when dealing with high-frequency currents, breaking the shield creates a high impedance for the common-mode return signal and the currents now have to find some unintended path back to the source and are likely to radiate even more.